# Printing an array of ascii values to the console as a string in assembly language 8086?

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, printing, x86-16

I'm new to assembly language coding and there's this program I'm trying to work out where I initialize an array of letters (in ascii), loop through it, and print it to the console window as a concatenated string. This is what I have so far:

```
.MODEL flat

.DATA

    name1 DB 4Ah, 69h, 6Dh, 6Dh, 79h

.CODE

main        PROC

            mov ecx, 0
            mov esi, offset name1

loop1:      

            mov dl, [esi]
            mov ah, 2
            inc esi
            inc ecx
            cmp ecx, 5
            jne loop1

endlp:      

            mov eax, 4c00h
            ret

main        ENDP

END
```

I'm pretty lost. Some of what I have here is from others trying to help me, so sorry if it looks messy.

Comment: First off you have to decide what target you are going to run the program on. Part of this code appears as if you might be trying to create a Win32 program and another part suggests 16-bit DOS. You can't mix them (if this is 16-bit DOS you don't use `.model flat`, `model small` should suffice. Mixing 16 bit and 32-bit code is doable if you know what you are doing. I'd recommend starting with 16-bit registers.

Comment: I suppose `mov ah,2` is preparing the call to int 21/2 (console echo) ... but then no `int 21` is done.

Comment: same at the end. you load the parameters for int 21/4c (quit to dos), but you don't call it

Answer (score 0):

Everything about your question cries DOS. I would suggest you use the *tiny* model for these simple demonstration programs.

- In the 16-bit environment it's natural to use 16-bit registers.
- To execute DOS api services you place the requested parameters in selected registers and store the function number in the `AH` register. Then you issue an `int 21h` call.
- A more efficient loop will count downward. Often you can avoid the need to compare before looping back because the flags have been set by the `dec` instruction.
- If you place the data of your program below the code that exits to DOS, you avoid mistakenly executing it.
- You can write an array of ASCII codes easier as a string. See the 3rd example.

```
 ORG 256            ;This asks for the tiny model

 mov  cx, 5
 mov  si, offset array
again:      
 mov  dl, [si]
 mov  ah, 02h
 int  21h            ;Display character
 inc  si
 dec  cx
 jnz  again

 mov  ax, 4C00h
 int  21h            ;Exit the program

array db 4Ah, 69h, 6Dh, 6Dh, 79h
```

An alternative program doesn't use the `CX` counter at all. It suffices to stop when the pointer `SI` is pointing beyond the last character.

```
 ORG  256            ;This asks for the tiny model

 mov  si, offset array
again:      
 mov  dl, [si]
 mov  ah, 02h
 int  21h            ;Display character
 inc  si
 cmp  si, offset array+5
 jb   again

 mov  ax, 4C00h
 int  21h            ;Exit the program

array db 4Ah, 69h, 6Dh, 6Dh, 79h
```

Another alternative program uses a zero delimiter on the array. To see if the delimiter was reached, you can write `cmp dl, 0` `je exit` but a bit better is to write `test dl, dl` `jz exit`.

```
 ORG  256            ;This asks for the tiny model

 mov  si, offset array
again:      
 mov  dl, [si]
 test dl, dl         ;Test for zero delimiter
 jz   exit
 mov  ah, 02h
 int  21h            ;Display character
 inc  si
 jmp  again
exit:
 mov  ax, 4C00h
 int  21h            ;Exit the program

array db 'Jimmy', 0
```